# Server always reports checked as true?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have some JS that adds a checked callback to checkboxes in a div and does an ajax call in that case:

```
$("#filter").on('change', '[type=checkbox]', function () {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "CalendarServices.aspx/UpdateFilter",
        data: 'id=' + this.value + '&checked=' + this.checked,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchResources');
        },
        error: function () {}
    });
```

But, when I check the POST values of the ajax call, 'checked' is always true. The id is correct, but checked is always true no matter how much I toggle it.

What could be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, I mean, clicking the checkbox.

Comment: The context of "this" is not the checkbox in this case.

Comment: How can I get the checked value then? The value I store works fine...

Comment: Works for me... http://jsfiddle.net/SVULU/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Bq37z/ - works

Comment: @Diodeus It is, it's not wrapped in a callback. Hence why the ID works. Also, `this.checked` works fine too: http://jsfiddle.net/FUppw/. The problem is server-side.

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
$(this).is(':checked')
```

or

```
$(this).prop('checked')
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to move out the this.checked to see if the ajax doesn't impact it.
Testing simply the onchange with an alert, it works.

```
$("#filter").on('change', '[type=checkbox]', function () {
    // dirty but works...
    var datas = 'id=' + this.value + '&checked=' + this.checked;
    console.log(this.checked);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "CalendarServices.aspx/UpdateFilter",
        data: datas,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchResources');
        },
        error: function () {}
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> But, when I check the POST values of the ajax call, 'checked' is always true. The id is correct, but checked is always true no matter how much I toggle it.

I have a hunch that this is not a problem in your javascript. But perhaps it's your server getting these values that's not reading them right.

Let's say you have 2 requests:

```
/foo/bar?checked=true
/foo/bar?checked=false
```

Now if your server is coded like this psuedocode:

```
if (params.checked) {
  doStuffWhenChecked();
} else {
  doStuffWhenNotChecked();
}
```

Then you have a problem.  This is because `params.checked` would be a string, which is either the string `"true"` or the string `"false"`.  And in most languages `"false"` is a truthy value, as is any non-empty string.

You need something more like this, which looks for the string `"true"` to do the checked thing.

```
if (params.checked == "true") {
  doStuffWhenChecked();
} else {
  doStuffWhenNotChecked();
}
```